# Realm in Swift3.0 unexpected status code: -34018

Tags: realm, swift3

run this code

```
SyncUser.authenticate(with: Credential.usernamePassword(username: username, password: password, actions: [.useExistingAccount]), server: Constants.syncAuthURL) { (user, error) in }
```

return -34018 error code

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::keychain::KeychainAccessException: Keychain returned unexpected status code: -34018
```

breakpoint in

```
_dispatch_once(dispatch_once_t *predicate,
    DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block){
if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(*predicate, ~0l) != ~0l) {
    dispatch_once(predicate, block);
} else {
    dispatch_compiler_barrier();
}
DISPATCH_COMPILER_CAN_ASSUME(*predicate == ~0l);}
```

THX

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-34018` means `errSecMissingEntitlement`. Try to specify an entitlements file, even if it contains no entitlements, can work around this problem.

See more at: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4158